# how to use glDrawElements with glBindVertexArray properly

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

what am trying to do is using `glDrawElements` to draw without redundancy of vertices as follow:

```
Model ModelManager::CreateModel(std::vector<glm::vec3>&vertices, std::vector<uint16_t>&vertexIndeces)
{
    //Vertecies
    GLuint vertexArray;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);

    GLuint vBufferId;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vBufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    GLuint iBufferId;
    glGenBuffers(1, &iBufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndeces.size(), vertexIndeces.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    //
    return Model(vertexArray, vBufferId, iBufferId, vertexIndeces.size());
}
```

and then when I draw :

```
void Model::Draw()
{
    if (vertexArray)
    {
        isFinishedIniting = true;
        glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, elementCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

shaders:

```
#version 120


void main()
{
        gl_Position= gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;

}

#version 120


void main()
{
    gl_FragColor=vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
}
```

the `obj` file am trying to load is easy I hand made it :

```
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 1.0 0.0
v -1.0 1.0 0.0
v -1.0 -1.0 0.0
v 1.0 -1.0 0.0

f 1/1/1 2/1/1 3/1/1
f 1/1/1 4/1/1 5/1/1
```

so it should show two red Triangles ,but it's not drawing anything to the screen!

Comment: This looks correct to me. I would suggest you take some steps back till you get something rendering as you expect, and then try and build slowly up and see where the rendering breaks. Can you render what you're after without using vertex array objects..?

Comment: The only thing I see out of the ordinary here has nothing to do with either of the API calls you mentioned. Rather, you have this weird `isFinishedIniting` logic in your ***Draw*** method. That would make sense if you were loading the model, but here you are basically drawing once and then after that the `if (!isFinishedIniting)` line prevents ever drawing your model again.

Comment: oh sorry I wrote that didn't copy paste it , so that was wrong I edited it lol

Comment: The first thing you should to is to check for errors using `glGetError`. When having OpenGL questions it often also helpful to tell which OS you use, and if it is an ATI or an Nvidia Card.

Comment: @t.niese yeh, but there is no errors/warnings :-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in this code:

1. The sizes passed to `glBufferData()` look wrong:

   ```
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   ...
   glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndeces.size(), vertexIndeces.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   ```

   Both `vertices` and `vertexIndeces()` are vectors. The `.size()` method on a `vector` gives the number of **elements**, while `glBufferData()` expects the size in **bytes**. To fix this, change the code to:

   ```
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0]),
                vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   ...
   glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndeces.size() * sizeof(vertexIndeces[0]),
                vertexIndeces.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   ```
2. The API calls use a mix of fixed function attributes and generic vertex attributes. Based on the version in the shader code, and the shader code itself (particularly the use of `gl_Vertex`), you're using OpenGL 2.1 level shaders with fixed function attributes. Therefore, you need to use `glEnableClientState()` and `glVertexPointer()` instead of `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `glVertexAttribPointer()`:

   ```
   glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
   ```

   You can use generic vertex attributes, but then you need to declare a variable of type `attribute` in the vertex shader, instead of using `gl_Vertex`.

Comment: yeah it was coz of the version , I have fixed the sizes but I didn't have time to edit here tho , thnx!